# Simulating isDestroyed() in Android

Tags: android, android-activity, ondestroy

I've found that I need to make a call to `isDestroyed()` to test whether an activity is no longer valid. I've done this and things work great.

However, the inclusion of `isDestroyed()` forces me to increase the Android API level to a level (17) that I'm not comfortable with. I'd prefer not to do this.

I'm thinking that I can simulate `isDestroyed()` simply by overriding `onDestroy()` in my activity. When that method is called, I can simply store this fact in a boolean and then use it to provide my own version of `isDestroyed()`  (changing the name of course).

Will something as simple as this work? I see lots of reference to `onDestroy()` not being called in some cases. Is there any other way to simulate this?

Comment: This won't work for earlier api levels. That being said, you could always use an annotation to say that this particular part of a test is only valid for higher level api levels, and not below a certain level. This would still allow you to write tests for lower api levels.

Answer (score 1):

Seeing as the framework code is:

```
public boolean isDestroyed() {
    return mDestroyed;
}

final void performDestroy() {
    mDestroyed = true;
    mWindow.destroy();
    mFragments.dispatchDestroy();
    onDestroy();
    if (mLoaderManager != null) {
        mLoaderManager.doDestroy();
    }
    if (mVoiceInteractor != null) {
        mVoiceInteractor.detachActivity();
    }
}
```

I'd say that you're safe enough to use your own flag set in `onDestroy`, you will get the same result as using the Framework's flag unless something crashes in `mWindow.destroy()` or `mFragments.dispatchDestroy()`

Answer (score 0):

It might work, depending on when you need to check `isDestroyed()`.

If you check for `isDestroyed()` in a `Fragment.onDestroy()` callback, a simulated implementation implemented as you describe will return `false`, while `Activity.isDestroyed()` will return `true`. If you check for `isDestroyed()` "later", it will work. You can verify this using the following tester app:

```
package com.example.test.myapplication;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private boolean mOnDestroyCalled;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, new MainFragment())
                    .commit();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        mOnDestroyCalled = true;
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    public boolean isDestroyed_SIMULATED() {
        return mOnDestroyCalled;
    }

    public static class MainFragment extends Fragment {
        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();
            final MainActivity mainActivity = (MainActivity)getActivity();
            dumpIsDestroyedImplementations("In Fragment.onDestroy() ", mainActivity);

            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    dumpIsDestroyedImplementations("A while later           ", mainActivity);
                }
            }, 500);
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            final TextView textView = new TextView(getActivity());
            textView.setText("Hello world!");
            return textView;
        }

        private void dumpIsDestroyedImplementations(String prefix, MainActivity mainActivity) {
            Log.i("IsDestroyedTest", prefix + "isDestroyed(): " +
                    mainActivity.isDestroyed() +
                    " isDestroyed_SIMULATED(): " + mainActivity.isDestroyed_SIMULATED());
        }
    }
}
```

If you run this, and then press the Back button on the device, `adb logcat -s IsDestroyedTest` will give you the following output:

```
I/IsDestroyedTest( 2143): In Fragment.onDestroy() isDestroyed(): true isDestroyed_SIMULATED(): false
I/IsDestroyedTest( 2143): A while later           isDestroyed(): true isDestroyed_SIMULATED(): true
```

To understand why, [take a look](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-5.1.1_r1/core/java/android/app/Activity.java) at how `isDestroyed()` is implemented.

```
public boolean isDestroyed() {
    return mDestroyed;
}

...

final void performDestroy() {
    mDestroyed = true;
    ...
    mFragments.dispatchDestroy();
    onDestroy();
    ...
}
```

In this case, we can conceptually rewrite it as follows:

```
final void performDestroy() {
    mDestroyed = true;
    ...
    MainFragment.onDestroy() // Called by mFragments.dispatchDestroy();
    mOnDestroyCalled = true; // From MainActivity.onDestroy()
    super.onDestroy(); // From MainActivity.onDestroy()
    ...
}
```

And it is easy to see why we get the logcat output we get.

Regarding `onDestroy()` not being called sometimes, that problem will not be affected by you simulating `isDestroyed()`. And generally, if it is not called, there are good reasons (the system urgently needs to free memory and don't have time to finalize Activity lifecycle calls, or there is no reason to actually destroy the activity). Regarding if there are other ways to simulate this, at least I can't think of any.